# Jenkins SonarQube step go to Warn

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I am slowly diving in to the pipeline groovy dsl of Jenkins. And I am trying to figure out how I can create a step that does sonar and reflects the quality gate message in the Jenkins buildserver.

At this moment I have the folowing step definded for sonar:

```
stage ('sonar') {
  mvn "-Dsonar.lang.patterns.jsp=notverified -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.server.example:9494 org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar -Dsonar.login=key
}
```

Now I want that when Maven gets the :

```
[INFO] Quality gate status: WARN
```

that it does not set it on `OK` or `Error` but makes that build step go `WARN` as well (so instead of the nice green or red a nice color of Yellow). I have been digging trough the documentation but as far as I can tell there is no real way to make a Step go to WARN state in any way its in essense binary. And there is noting in between any one a idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CloudBees support](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline-), you can set build result by setting `currentBuild.result` yourself, so, to get the yellow orb that indicates unstable status (failed unit tests), you can do this:

```
currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
```

Now, you want to do this when Sonar quality gate status is "WARN".

They [document how to do it](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/#waitforqualitygate-wait-for-sonarqube-analysis-to-be-completed-and-return-quality-gate-status): first you wrap your sonar execution with `withSonarQubeEnv('Your Sonar server')`, then you wait for server to call you back with the results with `waitForQualityGate()`:

```
stage("Build & SonarQube analysis") {
    node {
        withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
            sh 'mvn clean package sonar:sonar'
        }
    }
}

stage("Quality Gate Check"){
    timeout(time: 20, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        def qg = waitForQualityGate()
        if (qg.status == 'WARN') {
            currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>I have not tested this, I have an outdated version that I plan to upgrade when I have time, using a manually scripted approach that's 10 times more complicated than the above, I want to get rid of it and replace it with this solution... Not done yet but I'm sharing notes I collected.</sub>

Comment: Ill go try, this tomrow (my time zone). And let you kon.